# What do the numbers mean at the end of predicted variation opcode in and EPD entry?

Tags: pgn, fen

I'm writing an EPD (Extended Position Description) parser and I have a doubt about what numbers means at end of "predicted variation" opcode.

Look the follow EPD sample:

```
rq2r1k1/5pp1/p7/4bNP1/1p2P2P/5Q2/PP4K1/5R1R w - - bm Nxg7 BT-2630.1; ce 182; acs 0; acn 106652; pv 1.Nxg7 Kxg7 2.Qxf7+ Kh8 3.Qh7+ Kxh7 4.Rf7+ Kg6 5.Rf6+ Bxf6 6.h5+ Kxg5 (38.748) 112.9; c0 depth=8
```

As its possible to notice, the opcode `pv` ends with numbers `(38.748) 112.9`. That

I started from the [article in the Chess Programming Wiki](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Extended_Position_Description). There I found some related materials, like the [PGN specification](http://www.saremba.de/chessgml/standards/pgn/pgn-complete.htm#c16.2), that have a more elaborated EPD documentation an some links to [EPD entries examples](https://www.stmintz.com/ccc/index.php?id=137052). However, I can't find any explanation about the meaning of the numbers.

Does anyone have some material with a more elaborated documentation about the EPD (or PGN) format?

Comment: Your link to "EPD examples" is a duplicate of the link to the PGN spec.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a strict reading of the EPD spec, the example shown is malformed; the `pv` opcode should **only** contain a list of moves, not any commentary on it, which should be moved to other opcodes.  Indeed the move numbers should not be there either, only raw SAN moves.

I assume that some naive EPD author has simply dumped the output of an engine into it.

Indeed [following the discussion](https://www.stmintz.com/ccc/index.php?id=137127) from your (fixed) examples link, the first reply seems to agree with me:

> Crafty has an option to clean up epd (called epdpfdr) that produces
>   EPD output that most programs can read.  You have a few errors in your
>   output below.

…

> No numbers in the pv!
>   Like this: `Nxg7 Kxg7 Qxf7+ Kh8 Qh7+ Kxh7 Rf7+ Kg6 Rf6+ Bxf6`
>
> Also (a common mistake) is to put `...` in the front of the pv when it
>   is black to move.  This is not allowed.  You did not do that, but I
>   just wanted to mention it.

…

> This stuff:
>     `(73.507) 130.7;`
>   is not allowed except in the comments field.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I'm sure that I can follow the PGN specification as it is.